# Find an $N$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\ln n\over n^2}$ is between $\sum_{n=1}^N {\ln n\over n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N {\ln n\over n^2} + 0.005$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is an exercise from Calculus-2 course "Sequence and Series":

Find an $N$ so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\ln n\over n^2}$$ is between
$$\sum_{n=1}^N {\ln n\over n^2}$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^N {\ln n\over n^2} + 0.005$$

My solution:

I use the following inequality $$\int_{n+1}^{\infty}{\ln x\over x^2}dx={\ln(n+1)+1 \over n+1}< 0.005$$ But how to solve it then?

Instead, I use R to compute it and obtain the correct answer 1685.

R code:

```
## Q11
f <- function(x) log(x) / x^2
n <- 1e7
limit <- sum(f(x = 1:1e7))
for (i in 1:n){
  if(sum(f(x = 1:i)) < limit & limit < sum(f(x = 1:i)) + 0.005){
    print(i)
    break
  }
}
# [1] 1685
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Observe that your equation
$$
1+ \ln x = \frac{1}{200}x \tag1
$$ may be rewritten just by exponentiation as
$$
-\frac{x}{200}e^{-\dfrac{x}{200}}=-\frac{1}{200 \:e} \tag2
$$
which is of the form
$$
Xe^X=a
$$

then use (the correct branch of) the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to obtain

$$x= -200 \:W_{-1} \left( -\frac{1}{200 \:e}\right) \approx 1686.03$$

W|A returns [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2Bln%28x%29%3D0.005*x).

Answer (score 2):

Since Olivier Oloa gave the good answer, let me just show how good is the approximation of $W_{-1}(a)$ when $a$ is large.

The very first order gives $$W_{-1}(a)\approx \log (-a)-\log (-\log (-a))+\frac{\log (-\log (-a))}{\log (-a)}$$ So, for $a=-\frac{1}{200 \:e}$, this gives $W_{-1}(a)\approx -8.43079$ and so $x \approx 1686.16$.

Changing the $0.005$ for your problem to $0.0005$ would have given $x \approx 22005.9$ while the exact solution is $21997.4$.

Not bad, isn't it ?